# Rails 5 Query when using both single and multiple association relationships

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, active-record-query

I have a rails app with the following setup:

```
class Organization < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :user_orgs
    has_many :users, :through => :user_orgs
end

class UserOrg < ApplicationRecord
    #  organization_id      :integer
    #  user_id :integer
    belongs_to :organization
    belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
    #  car_id :integer
    has_many :user_orgs
    has_many :organizations, :through => :user_orgs
    belongs_to :car
end

class Car < ApplicationRecord
    #  brand :string
    has_many :users
end
```

What I am trying to do is to write a Rails 5 query so that it returns all organizations where a certain car attribute is set, i.e. return all organizations where there is a user who has a car with a given brand.

How can I join the Car class on the Organization when doing the query? Currently, I search for organizations based on User criteria by doing the following:

```
Organization.joins(:users).where("users.name = ?", name)
```

But I want to be able to add car criteria to the query as well.

Answer (score 0):

How about using this-

```
###add this scope in Organisation model that has - has_many :users
scope :get_users_by_carBrand, -> (brand) { includes(:cars).where(:cars=> {:name => brand} }

###this is the select query 
Organization.includes(:users).get_users_by_carBrand("BMW")
```

Comment: That looks like it would only search for users with a given name, not a car with a given name?

Comment: Sorry @milind, I had an error in my question (the car/user associations were reversed; fixed in the original summary now), so based on the actual structure, that solution wouldn't apply.

Comment: Thats Ok..check my updated answer by adding scope.Try to use it on rails console first..make few changes that fits your association.Let me know if its helpful.

Comment: I couldn't use that directly since when I do that, I get an error saying "Association named cars not available on organization". So what I did was I added that scope to the User model, got an array of user IDs which had that car brand, and then used that array in a query on the Organization. That did give me the results that I wanted, but it does take multiple queries.

Comment: Well yes..as it depends on your model associations...,now you have three models to handle..first user and cars and then use it to query Organisation.